# The number limit could be create of Messaging Service

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I using the Messaging Service(MS). I have a lot of clients using my Web, and every one of them needs to own their number or Alpha sender. So I will create a service in MS for each client, and I'm considering Twilio Messaging service have any number limit service I can create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a limit to the number of messaging services that you can create. There are no [errors](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors) related to the number of messaging services (though a messaging service can only have 400 numbers in the pool) and I could find no other documented limitations.